# Will the series $\sum \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n + o(n)}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

Recently I encountered a strengthened version of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5408/limit-of-the-sequence-nx-n-where-x-n1-log-1-x-n) question. Suppose $x_1 > 0$ and $x_{n + 1} = \log(1 + x_n)$. Prove that
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n(na_n - 2)}{\log n} = \frac{2}{3}$$

I tried to follow the method for the original question. Define $b_n = 1/a_n$. It appears that
$$b_{n + 1} = b_n + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{12b_n} + O\left(\frac{1}{b_n^2}\right)$$
Therefore
$$b_n = \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{12} \sum_{1 \leq k < n}\frac{1}{b_k} + O\left(\sum_{1 \leq k < n}\frac{1}{b_k^2}\right)$$
Now if we can prove that
$$\sum_{1 \leq k < n}\frac{1}{b_k} = 2\log n + O(1)$$
$$\sum_{1 \leq k < n}\frac{1}{b_k^2} = O(1)$$
Then the limit follows easily, since
$$\frac{n(na_n - 2)}{\log n} = \frac{n^2 - 2nb_n}{b_n\log n} = \frac{n/3 + O(n/\log n)}{b_n}$$
and we already know that $b_n/n \rightarrow 1/2$. The second asymptotic is already proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658627/proving-the-convergence-of-limit-and-series). However I don't know if the first asymptotic is correct or not. We know that $b_n = n/2 + o(n)$. If we can show that the series
$$\sum \frac{1}{n + o(n)} - \frac{1}{n}$$
converges, then we can conclude that $\sum 1/b_n = 2\ln n + O(1)$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{n+o(n)}-\frac{1}{n} = \frac{o(1)}{n+o(n)}$, but for example, take $\frac{1}{n\log(n)}$ and $\sum \frac{1}{n\log(n)}$ doesn't converge

Comment: Your claim does not hold in general, for instance when your $o(n)$ is very big, such as $o(n)=\frac{n}{\log(n)}$.

Comment: Maybe the condition could be weakened. We only need that $\frac{n - 2b_n}{\log n} \rightarrow 1/3$, hence $b_n = \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{6}\log n + o(\log n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that

$$o(n)=n\cdot \omega (n) \quad \omega (n)\to 0$$

therefore

$$\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n + o(n)}=\frac{\omega (n)}{n(1+\omega (n))}\sim \frac{\omega (n)}{n}$$

and the given series

- converges for $\omega (n)=\frac1n$
- diverges for $\omega (n)=\frac1{\log n}$
- $\ldots$

Comment: Small remark: be cautious with the alternating series, as convergence of $\sum n^{-1} \omega(n)$ does not imply convergence of $\sum n^{-1} (1+\omega(n))^{-1} \omega(n)$.

Comment: @D.Thomine yes of course! I did a bad example with that...thanks!